# firestore cloud functions not triggering

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am new to firebase cloud functions. So, I followed the tutorial in firebase youtube channel.
So, I created a function that should trigger when firestore document added,but it didn't trigger.

this is the function

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");

admin.initializeApp();

exports.whenAddData = functions.firestore
  .document("chats/{userId}")
  .onCreate((change, context) => {
    const msg = change.data().msg;
    const modifiedMsg = addImoji(msg);
    console.log("data changing");
    return change.ref({ msg: modifiedMsg });
  });

const addImoji = (msg) => {
  return msg.replace(/\bPizza\b/g, "  ");
};
```

firebase-functions version: "^3.6.1"

firestore db screenshot
[image]

Comment: add a screenshot of ur database

Comment: screenshot added

Comment: are you not getting     console.log("data changing");
?

Comment: yha i am not getting console log

Comment: also cheked functions log

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, your regex is wrong. It's case sensitive, which means the message from your screenshot "i love pizza" doesn't match "Pizza". To make it case insensitive (and thus match "Pizza", "pizza", "piZZA" ...) add the `i` flag at the end:

```js
const addImoji = (msg) => {
  return msg.replace(/\bpizza\b/gi, "");
};
```

Secondly, your function returns a database reference. It doesn't actually store the new data by calling `set()` or `update()`. Your code should be:

```js
return change.ref.update({ msg: modifiedMsg });
```

Any async Firebase function should return a promise (and `update()` returns a promise). If it doesn't, the function won't terminate correctly.

By returning the result of `update`, your function will keep running until the asynchronous work of writing the new `msg` to the database is completed.